# Is there any way to change the encoding of an exe file?

Tags: unpacking, encodings

I have an exe file and it will browse the xml, or txt files to display this exe file.

And the characters only display the exact language of that country when I switch the language of the computer to a certain fixed locale (eg locale chinese simplified "gb2132").

Is there any way for me to interfere with these character encodings through reverse engineering, so this exe file can browse unicode characters instead of having to switch the computer's locale?

This is the file.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nU9Wz0DIsGjPz2ebzEmfkqaIYxBE5b7_

[image: encoding issue]